# Don't sort on first column when other columns are sorted

Tags: datatables

I want my 1st column which is serial number to a fixed column with values. Currently this is also getting changed when the sorting is done for other columns.

I couldn't achieve this by making the sorting as false since it just removes the sorting option in the datatable rather than disable the sort even though the other columns are clicked for sorting

Requiirement

1. Serial Number - No Sort
2. Other columns - Sorting - Yes
3. However the serial number should not get changed at any point even when sorting applies in the datatable.

The below just makes the sorting false for a column but it doesn't solves the above problem

```
  $('#example').dataTable( {
 "aoColumns": [
  null,
  null,
  { "bSortable": false },
  null
 ]
 });
```

Please kindly help me on how to solve this issue

Thank you in advance for any.